# Install android studio on garuda linux

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, konsole

how can I install android studio on garuda linux using Terminal (fish konsole)
I have already tried to download android for debian but was unable to extract and install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**INSTALLING ANDROID STUDIO ON ~: fish - konsole**

On Arch Linux, snap can be installed from the Arch User Repository or by running a couple commands as follows.

**clonning snapd**

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/snapd.git

cd snapd

makepkg -si
```

Once installed, run the folowing command to enable snap communication socke.

```
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
```

To enable classic snap support, run the following

```
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
```

log out and back in again, or restart your system, to ensure snap’s paths are updated correctly.

**Installing Android Studio**

To install Android Studio, simply use the following command:

```
sudo snap install android-studio --classic
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/toolbox/) to easily install anything JetBrains, It's 2023.